# is there a way to change key name in local storage. for example:

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i want to delete the item with the key name of "1"

| key | item |
| --- | --- |
| "0" | "first item" |
| "1" | "second item" |
| "2" | "third item" |
| "3" | "fourth item" |

When i delete it it will look like this

| key | item |
| --- | --- |
| "0" | "first item" |
| "2" | "third item" |
| "3" | "fourth item" |

I want it to like like this  after i delete it

| key | item |
| --- | --- |
| "0" | "first item" |
| "1" | "third item" |
| "2" | "fourth item" |

i know you can't change the key name but you can set a new key items pair with a different key name and the same item key. then delete the previous key value pair.

please help me . i can't figure this out. i have been trying it for two days.

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: Do you want keys to be just a simple counter? If for example you have items from 0 to 1,000,000 and then you drop itens 10-19, all items from 20 to 1,000,000 should be renumbered to 11-999,990?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context why you need this ? There might be a simpler solution for you problem I assume .

Comment: @PascalLamers Yeah, this smells like an xy problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I am going on a limb here, but I try my luck and assume, the thing you are actually trying to do is to **maintain a list of items** and keep it in `localStorage` .

There is no problem with actually storing an array in `localStorage` as long as it is a string - and to convert an array into a string ( and be able to parse it back later ) you can use `JSON.stringify` (and `JSON.parse` to get it back)

### Maintain a list in `localStorage`

```js
function addNewItem (item) {

  let myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
  myList.push(item);
  localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(myList));

}

function removeItem (index) {
 
  let myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList", "[]"));
  myList.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(myList));

}
```

Comment: i have been thing about an algorithm for this. but then you help me realize that i can just store an array. wow . thank a lot